# How to remove device id from manually entered usb-serial driver

Tags: kernel, drivers, usb, usb-drive, ttyusb

I previously followed the answer in this question: [Attaching USB-Serial device with custom PID to ttyUSB0 on embedded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67936/attaching-usb-serial-device-with-custom-pid-to-ttyusb0-on-embedded?newreg=77c2eaf90f504613a637a40bd9a095b3)

Now, I need to revert that step so that the device id I echoed to new_id doesn't map to ttyUSB0 every time I connect it. The file, new_id, seems to have '0403 e0d0' permanently written to it now. I've tried to use the unbind file to no luck. There's also no "remove_id" file. Only bind, new_id, uevent, and unbind.

How can I revert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into this, and it does seem like `remove_id` was never implemented for `usb-serial`. Should be able to take the work in `drivers/usb/core/driver.c` and implement `remove_id` in `drivers/usb/serial/bus.c`.

Sorry for not having an easy answer.

Comment: Wouldn't reinstalling the kernel fix it?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik just a reboot would do it. No reinstall.

Comment: You can also do this without a reboot by removing then adding the serial module. `sudo modprobe -r usb_serial_simple; sudo modprobe usb_serial_simple`. This doesn't remove individual VID:PIDs that you added but will revert the driver back to it's fresh state.

Answer (score 0):

As @robbat2 states. The remove_id attribute isn't implemented for the generic usb-serial driver. Rather than rebooting the entire system though, you can revert your changes by just unloading and reloading the kernel module. Since this wipes the new_id device table you get your desired effect.

Remove the module

```
sudo modprobe -r usb_serial_simple
```

Reinsert the module

```
sudo modprobe usb_serial_simple
```